# APT and firefox are slow at startup with my wifi, but Google Chrome works fine

Tags: networking, apt, firefox

I am running Kubuntu 18.04 and whenever I download through the terminal with `apt` or `apt-get`, it takes about 10 seconds for the terminal to start downloading.

Firefox also takes about 5 to 10 seconds to start loading pages. Google Chrome loads them instantly though. This only happens when I connect to my own wifi or when I connect my laptop with an ethernet wire to my router, in other wifi networks everything is normal.

Comment: Since the problem seems to be related to your router, perhaps this is the way it works. Check for firmware updates.

Comment: Google Chrome loads them instantly though.